# How can I make the position of a gun relative to the player

Tags: python

I am using ursina game engine however this is mainly about the math so I don't think the engine matters.

In the engine there is no such thing as "front" so if I want a player to move front I have to use this mathematical formula:

```
player_x += player_x *cos(degrees)
player_z += player_z *cos(degrees)
```

This works for everything I throw at it, except for a weapon I am trying to put into the game. I want it to follow the player, which it does, but when it rotates, it rotates based on its own center, so the gun doesn't follow the player.

How can I make it so that the rotation of the weapon follows the player?

I can't just make it like:

```
gun.rotation_y = player.rotation_y
gun.x = player.x
gun.z = player.z
```

because then it would be in the player, and if I move it forward, it will rotate on its own center, so it wouldn't be aligned with the gun.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make smth like

```
gun.rotation_y = player.rotation_y
gun.x = player.x + (and put value here so it near player e.g 10)
gun.z = player.z + (and put value here so it near player e.g 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent the gun to the player with `gun.parent = player` and position it how you want. It will then move along with the player.

For the forward movement you can just do `player.position += player.forward * held_keys['w']`.